# feeding data present in series seperated by , into a columns of data frame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am a beginner in python. I am working on a project where I have data in following pattern:

Data in json file looks like this :

"price_time":[1398823200,1403154000,1403247600,1403301600,1403380800],"price_value":[901,909,918,927,936],],"salesRank_value":[2176,2318,2192,1801,1829]

df.head() command looks like this:

```
>>> df.head() 
                                            1974-12-11 20:55:21
price_time    [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600, 140330160...
price_value   [901, 909, 918, 927, 936, 945, 954, 963, 972, ...
rating_time                                        [1475972640]
rating_value                                               [43]
review_count  [6558, 6560, 6561, 6562, 6564, 6566, 6568, 656...

df = pd.read_json('results.json')
In [] : print(df.head()) 
output : 
price_time       [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600, 140330160...
price_value      [901, 909, 918, 927, 936, 945, 954, 963, 972, ...
salesRank_value  [2176, 2318, 2192, 1801, 1829, 2207, 1757, 177...
```

I want to transform this data into following pattern:

```
price_time   price_value  salesRank_value
1398823200   901          2176
1403154000   909          2318
1403247600   918          2192
```

and so on...
The code which i wrote is here but i am unable to get the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd


df1={}
df1['price_time'] = df.loc['price_time']
df1['price_value'] = df.loc['price_value']
print(df1)

output:
{'price_value': 1974-12-11 20:55:21    [901, 909, 918, 927, 936, 945, 954, 963, 972, ...
Name: price_value, dtype: object, 'price_time': 1974-12-11 20:55:21    [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600, 140330160...
Name: price_time, dtype: object}
```

Comment: Do you want to print it that way or store it in a file that way or something else?(Since they are already stored in list according to corresponding location it shouldnt need sorting)

Comment: No, i do not want to print it that way, i have imported this data from the json file, i want to get this in tabular(desired pattern in question) form and  then analyze it further.

Comment: What *exactly* does your JSON data look like? What *exactly* does your `df` look like? Maybe print the result of `df.head(10)` and share it here.

Comment: Like juanpa.arrivillaga said, can you please add a sample of your file please.

Comment: df.head(10) gives result as follows. It looks exactly like i mentioned in question.
price_time       [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600, 140330160...
price_value      [901, 909, 918, 927, 936, 945, 954, 963, 972, ...
salesRank_value  [2176, 2318, 2192, 1801, 1829, 2207, 1757, 177...

Comment: No. Why would you post it in a comment? Edit the question and post it there. And please be precise, what *exactly* are you talking about.

Comment: @kart check out the answer i have posted, if the input data isn't exactly looking like this can you give a minimal complete example where i can receive df.head() to check how it looks like exactly. Also can you please use df.head() only instead of print so i can see how the string looks like.

Comment: @kart can you post what only df.head() looks like(just open it using python ide and then write df.head() after reading json file) it seems easier to parse, i am making the parser the json file now

Comment: >>> df.head()
                                            1974-12-11 20:55:21
price_time    [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600, 140330160...
price_value   [901, 909, 918, 927, 936, 945, 954, 963, 972, ...
rating_time                                        [1475972640]
rating_value                                               [43]
review_count  [6558, 6560, 6561, 6562, 6564, 6566, 6568, 656...

Comment: @iamnotgoogle i hope this may help you in getting the pith of it.

Comment: @kart - I think the best is if add link to your `json` file if data are not confidental - dropbox, gdocs, wetransfer. Then is possible some better solution is available.

Comment: @kart According to the text you have shown resides in your json file i have parsed it, edited in the answer. Check if that works for your. If it doesn't then i need a sample of your json file to see how the text looks different to the interpreter.(df.head() looks way more horrible than the json file so i have parsed the json file only)

Answer (score 0):

```
price_time = [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600, 140330160]
price_value  =  [901, 909, 918, 927]
salesRank_value = [2176, 2318, 2192, 1801]

listdata = zip(price_time,price_value,salesRank_value)
print listdata
```

Comment: <zip object at 0x0501D580>

Comment: As i said i am importing the data from json file, i don't have the data in the format used by you. It is simply like this : 
price_time [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600, 140330160...],
price_value [901, 909, 918, 927, 936, 945, 954, 963, 972, ...],
salesRank_value[2176, 2318, 2192, 1801, 1829, 2207, 1757, 177...]...

and as the data is huge, I can not edit each field individually.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are having the data in single string(lines are differentiated by newline character) or in a file then you can use the following one liners.
Assuming data in single string variable data=df.head() looks something like this:

```
'price_time       [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600]\nprice_value      [901, 909, 918]\nsalesRank_value  [2176, 2318, 2192]'
```

you can use following to get the required array:

```
array=[a.split() for a in data.replace("[","").replace(",","").replace("]","").split('\n')]
```

Output(2D array with each inside array containing each row with 1st element as name of row and remaining as data):

```
[['price_time', '1398823200', '1403154000', '1403247600'], ['price_value', '901', '909', '918'], ['salesRank_value', '2176', '2318', '2192']]
```

If you have the data in file data.txt like this:

```
price_time       [1398823200, 1403154000, 1403247600]
price_value      [901, 909, 918]
salesRank_value  [2176, 2318, 2192]
```

Then use the following:

```
array=[line.replace("[","").replace(",","").replace("]","").split() for line in open('data.txt')]
```

And the output again in 2D array like before:

```
[['price_time', '1398823200', '1403154000', '1403247600'], ['price_value', '901', '909', '918'], ['salesRank_value', '2176', '2318', '2192']]
```

For the json file's data as given by you:

```
"price_time":[1398823200,1403154000,1403247600,1403301600,1403380800],"price_value":[901,909,918,927,936],"salesRank_value":[2176,2318,2192,1801,1829]
```

Use this without needing pandas:

```
array=[b.split() for b in  open('data.json').read().replace('"',"").replace(":["," ").replace("],","\n").replace(","," ").replace("]","").split('\n')]
print array
```

(There is a neater way to remove non-alphanumeric characters, but since i needed to format string as i wanted i used this)
The output like earlier in a 2D array:

```
[['price_time', '1398823200', '1403154000', '1403247600', '1403301600', '1403380800'], ['price_value', '901', '909', '918', '927', '936'], ['salesRank_value', '2176', '2318', '2192', '1801', '1829']]
```

See the result in tabular form:

```
for z in range(len(array[0])):
 temp=''
 for y in range(len(array)):
  temp+=array[y][z]+'\t'
 temp+='\n'
 print temp
```

Output:

```
price_time      price_value     salesRank_value

1398823200      901     2176

1403154000      909     2318

1403247600      918     2192

1403301600      927     1801

1403380800      936     1829
```

For prettier output, use this:

```
s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in array]
lens = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*s)]
fmt = ' '.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
print '\n'.join(table)
```

Output:

```
price_time      1398823200 1403154000 1403247600 1403301600 1403380800
price_value     901        909        918        927        936
salesRank_value 2176       2318       2192       1801       1829
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The output comes exactly the way you have given, can you tell me how can i arrange it in the tabular format mentioned above in the question.

Actually, what it stands for is, 901 was the price value of this particular product at this(1398823200) time. I want to rearrange the data so that it would be easy for me to visualize. I hope this is making sense to you.

Comment: @kart well technically this is kind of a tabular form. See, the array[0][1] element contains price_time=1398823200 for the item, for same item array[1][1] contains price value for the item 901 and array[2][1] contains 2176 as sales rank of the item. And array[0][0] array[1][0] array[2][0] contains their respective heads.

Comment: @kart added the code to print it to show you how it looks in tabular form

Comment: @kart i didn't get the upvote points. Its ok if you don't want to :D

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation may be that's why... But I did that... Anyways... Thanks for that..